# Cordova with JQM works on emulator, not on device, ios and android

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, case-sensitive

For anyone who does not want to waste as much time on this issue as I have done:

Situation:
- You have created an app with Cordova 6.5.0, using jQuery and JQM
- The app functions completely well in the iOS emulator.
- The app does not show JQM markup in the TestFlight engine of apple developer.

Question:
- How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Answer:
- The devices are capital sensitive to the file location of the files you refer to. For instance: if the style sheet on the device is "css/fubar.css", it will fail in the device (but not in the emulator) when you use "css/Fubar.css".